# Swagger UI: required fields in objects

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Hello i have a request body like this:

```
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        type: object
        required:
          - brand
          - model
          - capacity
        properties:
          brand:
            type: string
            example: Brand
          model:
            type: string
            example: Model
          capacity:
            type: object
            properties:
              passengers:
                type: number
                example: 10
              luggage:
                type: number
                example: 200
```

How can I set passengers as required field?

I tried with a schema like this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    capacity:
    type: object
    required:
      - passengers
    properties:
      passengers:
        type: number
        example: 10
      luggage:
        type: number
        example: 200
```

with this in request body:

```
capacity:
   $ref: "#/components/schemas/capacity"
```

But it does not work

Comment: All looks good! what is the problem? are you getting any error? check the proper tabling below `capacity:` schema check working SS https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPeLa.png

Comment: I split openapi.yaml in files, I use a file named vehicle.yaml with elements Response, Request, Parameter & Capacity, I resolved putting capacity in definitions element. Thanks